# Why does Proguard remove method's "bridge" modifier?

Tags: java, scala, proguard, obfuscation

I've noticed that Proguard removes method's bridge modifier even if the class excluded from obfuscation with a `-keep` property. How can I avoid this behaviour? It breaks integration with third-party libraries. 
So I have a Scala function object that has method `apply`. Before obfuscation:

```
scala> classOf[TestFunction].getMethods.filter(m => m.getName == "apply" && !m.isBridge)
res0: Array[java.lang.reflect.Method] = Array(public final double TestFunction.apply(java.lang.Object))
```

After obfuscation:

```
scala> classOf[TestFunction].getMethods.filter(m => m.getName == "apply" && !m.isBridge)
res0: Array[java.lang.reflect.Method] = Array(public final double TestFunction.apply(java.lang.Object), public final java.lang.Object TestFunction.apply(java.lang.Object))
```

I need those 2 cases be similar.

Proguard version is 5.3

**UPD** I also keeping the following attributes:

```
-keepattributes Signature,*Annotation*
-keepattributes InnerClasses,EnclosingMethod
-keepattributes SourceFile,MethodParameters,Synthetic,Code,LineNumberTable
```